# Apply Color Filter with xml in ImageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I've got an ImageView and programmatically I can change its color using `imageView.setColorFilter(Color.RED)`.
There is something similar using xml??

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Yes, it's `android:tint`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)) you have more info.

Comment: It will break if you use multiple ImageViews with the same drawable. You need to mutate the drawable first.

Comment: @OliverDixon care to explain?

Comment: @mDroidd drawables on android share a common state. Read more here - http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/

Comment: `android:tint` is deprecated, use `app:tint`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I apply that code line in xml

```
                        app:tint="@color/white_color"
```

full code

```
                           <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_show_password"
                                app:tint="@color/white_color"
                                />
```

Answer (score 0):

I still use `android:tint`. There is red line under the code showing that it should use `app:tint`. I use it for notification but I don't know why it doesn't work for me to use `app:tint`.